# What are the two linked contacts under "Myself"?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In my phone, there's a "Myself" contact that can't be deleted or renamed, which has two linked contacts inside it. Those can't be unlinked or deleted either. Both contacts are marked as "Phone contact".

Why are there two and why are they not unlinkable? Can I link another contact under "Myself"? I want to add my phone number there; which of the two should I add this to?